# I can demonstrate P → Q but not the equivalent (¬Q→¬P)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to demonstrate that $P \to Q$ and $ \lnot Q \to \lnot P$ are equivalent, but I just can't resolve how to get from $P \to Q$ to $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$.

From $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$ to $P \to Q$:

1. Conditional law
   $(\lnot Q \to \lnot P)  \implies  (\lnot\lnot Q \lor \lnot P)$
2. Doble negation law
   $(\lnot\lnot Q \lor \lnot P)  \implies   Q \lor \lnot P$
3. Finally conditional again
   $\lnot P \lor Q    \implies   P \to Q$

How can I demonstrate the opposite?

Comment: "Conditional law" is an equivalence.

Comment: As is the double negation law (in classical logics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse direction!

These are all *equivalences* that you are using, so you can just go the other way around:

$$P\rightarrow Q \overset{Conditional Law}{\Rightarrow} \neg P \lor Q \overset{Double Negation}{\Rightarrow} \neg \neg Q \lor \neg P \overset{Conditional Law}{\Rightarrow} \neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$$

And by the way, you may want to throw in a step to go between $\neg P \lor Q$ and $Q \lor \neg P$ using Commutation. So, doing both directions at once:

$$P\rightarrow Q \overset{Conditional Law}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$ \neg P \lor Q \overset{Commutation}{\Leftrightarrow} $$

$$ Q \lor \neg P \overset{Double Negation}{\Leftrightarrow} $$

$$\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P \overset{Conditional Law}{\Leftrightarrow} $$

$$\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$$